# How can I build Android application for Oracle database using Buildozer?

Tags: android, python, oracle, kivy, buildozer

I have a big problem on Kivy. Can you help me?

I develope Stock Control Application for my company. My company use Oracle Database. I wrote code with Kivy,Python and I used cx_Oracle for connect our database. Its work in my PC perfect. But it does not work my Android Phone. I build a APK using Buildozer. After I take Error, I write log. That's the error I get:

```
python  :  ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

My Android Phone did not found cx_Oracle. I do not reach Oracle Database on my phone and application does not work. Is there any way you can suggest?

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/python
    # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
    from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
    from kivy.properties import StringProperty
    from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.properties import ListProperty
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    import cx_Oracle
    import os, sys

    Builder.load_string('''

    #:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button

    <GirisEkrani>:
        BoxLayout:
            id: login_layout
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: [10,50,10,50]
            spacing: 50

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Label:
                    text: '*'
                    font_size: 18
                    halign: 'left'
                    text_size: root.width-20, 20

                TextInput:
                    id: username
                    multiline:False
                    font_size: 28
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Label:
                    text: '*'
                    halign: 'left'
                    font_size: 18
                    text_size: root.width-20, 20
                TextInput:
                    id: passwd
                    multiline:False
                    password:True
                    font_size: 28

            Button:
                text: "*"
                font_size: 24
                on_press: root.login()


    <GirisOnayEkrani>:
        karsilama_yazisi: karsilama_yazisi

        BoxLayout:
            id: kutu
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: [10,50,10,50]
            spacing: 50

            Image:
                source: "./dogru.png"
            Label:
                id: karsilama_yazisi
                text: "*"

            Button:
                text: "Stok Kontrol"
                font_size: 24
                on_press: root.envanter()

            Button:
                text: "*"
                font_size: 24
                on_press: root.talepsikayet()



    <GirisRedEkrani>:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Image:
                source: "./yanlis.png"
            Label:
                text: "*"
            Button:
                text: "*"
                on_press: root.anaEkranaDon()

    <EnvanterKontrolEkrani>:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: [50,150,50,150]
            spacing: 300

            Button:
                text: "*"
                size_hint_y: None
                font_size: 20
                on_press: root.ekle()

            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'center'
                anchor_y: 'center'

                ScrollView:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '500dp'

                    MyGrid:
                        cols: 3
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        spacing: '2dp'

    <EklemeEkrani>:
        BoxLayout:
            id: login_layout
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: [10,50,10,50]
            spacing: 30

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Label:
                    text: "*"
                    font_size: 18
                    halign: 'left'
                    text_size: root.width-20, 20

                TextInput:
                    id: partno
                    multiline:False
                    font_size: 28
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Label:
                    text: '*'
                    halign: 'left'
                    font_size: 18
                    text_size: root.width-20, 20
                TextInput:
                    id: miktar
                    multiline:False
                    font_size: 28

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Label:
                    text: '*'
                    halign: 'left'
                    font_size: 18
                    text_size: root.width-20, 20
                TextInput:
                    id: tarih
                    multiline:False
                    font_size: 28

            Button:
                text: "*"
                font_size: 24
                on_press: root.eklemek()



    <TalepSikayetEkrani>:
        BoxLayout:
            id: login_layout
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: [10,50,10,50]
            spacing: 15


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Label:
                    text: '*'
                    halign: 'left'
                    font_size: 16
                    text_size: root.width-20, 20

                ComboEdit:
                    id: birim
                    multiline:False
                    font_size: 20
                    options:
                        [Button(text = '*', size_hint_y=None, height=30),
                        Button(text = '*', size_hint_y=None, height=30),
                        Button(text = '*', size_hint_y=None, height=30)]

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Label:
                    text: '*'
                    halign: 'left'
                    font_size: 16
                    text_size: root.width-20, 20

                ComboEdit:
                    id: form
                    multiline:False
                    font_size: 20
                    options:
                        [Button(text = '*', size_hint_y=None, height=30),
                        Button(text = '*', size_hint_y=None, height=30),
                        Button(text = '*', size_hint_y=None, height=30)]

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Label:
                    text: '*'
                    halign: 'left'
                    font_size: 16
                    text_size: root.width-20, 20

                ComboEdit:
                    id: onem
                    multiline:False
                    font_size: 20
                    options:
                        [Button(text = '*', size_hint_y=None, height=30),
                        Button(text = '*', size_hint_y=None, height=30),
                        Button(text = '*', size_hint_y=None, height=30)]

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'           
                Label:
                    text: '*'
                    halign: 'left'
                    font_size: 18
                    text_size: root.width-20, 20
                TextInput:
                    id: konu
                    multiline:False
                    font_size: 20


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'           
                Label:
                    text: '*'
                    halign: 'left'
                    font_size: 18
                    text_size: root.width-20, 20
                TextInput:
                    id: mesaj
                    multiline:False
                    font_size: 20

            Button:
                text: "*"
                font_size: 24
                on_press: root.formekle()


    <TalepSikayetOnayEkrani>:
        karsilama_yazisi: karsilama_yazisi

        BoxLayout:
            id: kutu
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: [10,50,10,50]
            spacing: 50

            Image:
                source: "./true.png"
            Label:
                id: karsilama_yazisi
                text: "*"

            Button:
                text: "Anasayfaya Don"
                font_size: 24
                on_press: root.anasayfa()



    <PlayerRecord>:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '30dp'
        width: '100dp'

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 0.2, 0.2, 0.2
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size


    <RootWidget>:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        id: kok
        GirisEkrani:
            id: giris
            name: "giris_ekrani"
        GirisOnayEkrani:
            id: onay
            name: "giris_basarili"
        GirisRedEkrani:
            id: red
            name: "giris_hatali"
        EnvanterKontrolEkrani:
            id:envanter
            name: "envanter_kontrol"
        EklemeEkrani:
            id:ekle
            name: "ekleme"
        TalepSikayetEkrani:
            id:talepsikayet
            name: "talep_sikayet"

        TalepSikayetOnayEkrani:
            id:talepsikayetonay
            name: "talep_onay"

    ''')




    class GirisEkrani(Screen):
        def login(self):
            if self.ids.username.text == "*" and\
                self.ids.passwd.text == "*":

                self.manager.current = "giris_basarili"

            else:
                self.manager.current = "giris_hatali"


    class GirisOnayEkrani(Screen):
        def envanter(self):
            self.manager.current = "envanter_kontrol"
        def talepsikayet(self):
            self.manager.current = "talep_sikayet"

    class EnvanterKontrolEkrani(Screen):
        def ekle(self):
            self.manager.current = "ekleme"

    class TalepSikayetEkrani(Screen):
        def formekle(self):
            if len(self.ids.birim.text) > 0 and\
               len(self.ids.form.text) > 0 and\
               len(self.ids.onem.text) > 0 and\
               len(self.ids.konu.text) > 0 and\
               len(self.ids.mesaj.text) > 0:
                con = cx_Oracle.connect('*/*@*/*')
                rows = [(str(self.ids.birim.text), str(self.ids.form.text), str(self.ids.onem.text), str(self.ids.konu.text), str(self.ids.mesaj.text))]
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.executemany("INSERT INTO * (birim , form, onem, konu, mesaj) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)", rows)
                con.commit()
                self.manager.current = "talep_onay"
                self.ids.birim.text = ""
                self.ids.form.text = ""
                self.ids.onem.text = ""
                self.ids.konu.text = ""
                self.ids.mesaj.text = ""
            else:
                self.manager.current = "giris_hatali"


    class ComboEdit(TextInput):

        options = ListProperty(('', ))

        def __init__(self, **kw):
            ddn = self.drop_down = DropDown()
            ddn.bind(on_select=self.on_select)
            super(ComboEdit, self).__init__(**kw)

        def on_options(self, instance, value):
            ddn = self.drop_down
            ddn.clear_widgets()
            for widg in value:
                widg.bind(on_release=lambda btn: ddn.select(btn.text))
                ddn.add_widget(widg)

        def on_select(self, *args):
            self.text = args[1]

        def on_touch_up(self, touch):
            if touch.grab_current == self:
                self.drop_down.open(self)
            return super(ComboEdit, self).on_touch_up(touch)


    class TalepSikayetOnayEkrani(Screen):
        def anasayfa(self):
            self.manager.current = "giris_ekrani"


    class EklemeEkrani(Screen):
        def eklemek(self):
            if len(self.ids.partno.text) > 1 and\
               len(self.ids.miktar.text) > 1 and\
               len(self.ids.tarih.text) > 1:
                con = cx_Oracle.connect('*/*@*/*')
                rows = [(str(self.ids.partno.text), str(self.ids.miktar.text), str(self.ids.tarih.text))]
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.executemany("INSERT INTO * (part_no, qty_on_hand, tarih) VALUES (:1, :2, :3)", rows)
                con.commit()
                self.manager.current = "giris_basarili"
                self.ids.partno.text = ""
                self.ids.miktar.text = ""
                self.ids.tarih.text = ""
            else:
                self.manager.current = "giris_hatali"




    class GirisRedEkrani(Screen):
        def anaEkranaDon(self):
            self.manager.current = "giris_ekrani"


    class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
        pass


    class TableHeader(Label):
        pass


    class PlayerRecord(Label):
        pass


    class MyGrid(GridLayout):

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.fetch_data_from_database()
            self.display_scores()

        def fetch_data_from_database(self):
            con = cx_Oracle.connect('*/*@*/*')

            cur=con.cursor()
            cur.execute('''select part_no, qty_on_hand, tarih from *''')

            liste =[{'Part No': 'Part No', 'Quantity On Hand': 'Quantity On Hand', 'Expiration Date': 'Expiration Date'}]


            for result in cur:

                liste.append({'Part No': result[0], 'Quantity On Hand': str(result[1]), 'Expiration Date': str(result[2])})

            self.data = liste


        def display_scores(self):
            self.clear_widgets()
            for i in range(len(self.data)):           
                row = self.create_player_info(i)
                for item in row:
                    self.add_widget(item)


        def create_player_info(self, i):
            first_column = PlayerRecord(text=self.data[i]['Part No'])
            second_column = PlayerRecord(text=self.data[i]['Quantity On Hand'])
            third_column = PlayerRecord(text=self.data[i]['Expiration Date'])
            return [first_column, second_column, third_column]

    class CemApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return RootWidget()

    if __name__ in ('__main__','__android__'):
        CemApp().run()
```

Note: I hid my company data with "*"

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the cx_Oracle module in your APK. However, cx_Oracle is a compiled C module so python-for-android needs a [recipe](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/) in order to compile it (for reference [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes) are all the existing recipes). There is not yet such a recipe, but you can try to write one. You probably want a [CompiledComponentsPythonRecipe](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/#using-a-compiledcomponentspythonrecipe).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Its hard to write a recipe for me because I'm lower level for this. Is there another way to add cx_Oracle in Android Phone ?